# Cannot start ruby app on uwsgi

Tags: ruby, redmine, uwsgi

I am getting the following error while starting uwsgi ruby app redmine:

```
Thu Apr 30 03:20:14 2015 - rails app /opt/redmine/ ready
Thu Apr 30 03:20:14 2015 - non-rack rails version detected...loading thin adapter...
Thu Apr 30 03:20:14 2015 - /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require': cannot load such file -- thin (LoadError)
Thu Apr 30 03:20:14 2015 -      from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
Thu Apr 30 03:20:14 2015 -      from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
Thu Apr 30 03:20:14 2015 -      from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
```

I have run 'gem install thin' but this did not help.
Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed this error with adding a line to uwsgi's redmine.ini:

```
rack = /opt/redmine/config.ru
```